# Time dependent 1D Schrodinger equation C++

Tags: c++, physics, pde

I wrote the code in C++ which solves the time-dependent 1D Schrodinger equation for the anharmonic potential V = x^2/2 + lambda*x^4, using Thomas algorithm. My code is working and I animate the results in Mathematica, to check what is going on. I test the code against the known solution for the harmonic potential (I put lambda = 0), but the animation shows that abs(Psi) is changing with time, and I know that is not correct for the harmonic potential. Actually, I see that in one point it time it becomes constant, but before that is oscillating.

So I understand that I need to have constant magnitude of the wave function over the time interval, but I don't know how to do it, or where am I doing mistake. 
Here is my code and the animation for 100 time steps and 100 points on the grid.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <complex>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// Mandatory parameters
const int L = 1; //length of domain in x direction
const int tmax = 10; //end time
const int nx = 100, nt = 100; //number of the grid points and time steps respectively
double lambda; //dictates the shape of the potential (we can use lambda = 0.0 
               // to test the code against the known solution for the harmonic 
               // oscillator)
complex<double> I(0.0, 1.0); //imaginary unit

// Derived parameters
double delta_x = 1. / (nx - 1);

//spacing between the grid points
double delta_t = 1. / (nt - 1);

//the time step
double r = delta_t / (delta_x * delta_x); //used to simplify expressions for 
                                          // the coefficients of the lhs and 
                                          // rhs of the matrix eqn

// Algorithm for solving the tridiagonal matrix system
vector<complex<double> > thomas_algorithm(vector<double>& a,
                                          vector<complex<double> >& b,
                                          vector<double>& c,
                                          vector<complex<double> >& d)
{

// Temporary wave function
    vector<complex<double> > y(nx + 1, 0.0);

// Modified matrix coefficients
    vector<complex<double> > c_prime(nx + 1, 0.0);
    vector<complex<double> > d_prime(nx + 1, 0.0);

// This updates the coefficients in the first row
    c_prime[0] = c[0] / b[0];
    d_prime[0] = d[0] / b[0];

// Create the c_prime and d_prime coefficients in the forward sweep
    for (int i = 1; i < nx + 1; i++)
    {
        complex<double> m = 1.0 / (b[i] - a[i] * c_prime[i - 1]);
        c_prime[i] = c[i] * m;
        d_prime[i] = (d[i] - a[i] * d_prime[i - 1]) * m;
    }

// This gives the value of the last equation in the system
    y[nx] = d_prime[nx];

// This is the reverse sweep, used to update the solution vector
    for (int i = nx - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        y[i] = d_prime[i] - c_prime[i] * y[i + 1];
    }
    return y;
}

void calc()
{

// First create the vectors to store the coefficients
    vector<double> a(nx + 1, 1.0);
    vector<complex<double> > b(nx + 1, 0.0);
    vector<double> c(nx + 1, 1.0);
    vector<complex<double> > d(nx + 1, 0.0);
    vector<complex<double> > psi(nx + 1, 0.0);
    vector<complex<double> > phi(nx + 1, 0.0);
    vector<double> V(nx + 1, 0.0);
    vector<double> x(nx + 1, 0);
    vector<vector<complex<double> > > PSI(nt + 1,
                                          vector<complex<double> >(nx + 1,
                                                                   0.0));
    vector<double> prob(nx + 1, 0);

// We don't have the first member of the left diagonal and the last member 
// of the right diagonal
    a[0] = 0.0;
    c[nx] = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nx + 1; i++)
    {
        x[i] = (-nx / 2) + i; // Values on the x axis
        // Eigenfunction of  the harmonic oscillator in the ground state
        phi[i] = exp(-pow(x[i] * delta_x, 2) / 2) / (pow(M_PI, 0.25)); 
        // Anharmonic potential
        V[i] = pow(x[i] * delta_x, 2) / 2 + lambda * pow(x[i] * delta_x, 4);
        // The main diagonal coefficients
        b[i] = 2.0 * I / r - 2.0 + V[i] * delta_x * delta_x; 
    }

    double sum0 = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nx + 1; i++)
    {
        PSI[0][i] = phi[i]; // Initial condition for the wave function
        sum0 += abs(pow(PSI[0][i], 2)); // Needed for the normalization
    }
    sum0 = sum0 * delta_x;

    for (int i = 0; i < nx + 1; i++)
    {
        PSI[0][i] = PSI[0][i] / sqrt(sum0); // Normalization of the initial 
                                            // wave function
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < nt; j++)
    {
        PSI[j][0] = 0.0;
        PSI[j][nx] = 0.0; // Boundary conditions for the wave function
        d[0] = 0.0;
        d[nx] = 0.0; // Boundary conditions for the rhs

// Fill in the current time step vector d representing the rhs
        for (int i = 1; i < nx + 1; i++)
        {
            d[i] = PSI[j][i + 1]
                    + (2.0 - 2.0 * I / r - V[i] * delta_x * delta_x) * PSI[j][i]
                    + PSI[j][i - 1];
        }

// Now solve the tridiagonal system
        psi = thomas_algorithm(a, b, c, d);

        for (int i = 1; i < nx; i++)
        {
            PSI[j + 1][i] = psi[i]; // Assign values to the wave function
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nx + 1; i++)
        {
            // Probability density of the wave function in the next time step
            prob[i] = abs(PSI[j + 1][i] * conj(PSI[j + 1][i])); 
        }
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nx + 1; i++)
        {
            sum += prob[i] * delta_x;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nx + 1; i++)
        {
            // Normalization of the wave function in the next time step
            PSI[j + 1][i] /= sqrt(sum); 
        }
    }

// Opening files for writing the results
    ofstream file_psi_re, file_psi_imag, file_psi_abs, file_potential,
            file_phi0;
    file_psi_re.open("psi_re.dat");
    file_psi_imag.open("psi_imag.dat");
    file_psi_abs.open("psi_abs.dat");

    for (int i = 0; i < nx + 1; i++)
    {
        file_psi_re << fixed << x[i] << "  ";
        file_psi_imag << fixed << x[i] << "  ";
        file_psi_abs << fixed << x[i] << "  ";
        for (int j = 0; j < nt + 1; j++)
        {
            file_psi_re << fixed << setprecision(6) << PSI[j][i].real() << "  ";
            file_psi_imag << fixed << setprecision(6) << PSI[j][i].imag()
                    << "  ";
            file_psi_abs << fixed << setprecision(6) << abs(PSI[j][i]) << "  ";
        }
        file_psi_re << endl;
        file_psi_imag << endl;
        file_psi_abs << endl;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    calc();
    return 0;
}
```

[The black line is abs(psi), the red one is Im(psi) and the blue one is Re(psi).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpEpm.gif)

Comment: Do you think it is do to rounding error? After all, the Tridiagonal Matrix Algorithm is not stable.

Comment: 2 pences advice, if you use TDD you will reduce your debug time to almost zero

Comment: How do you think rounding error, can you explain it to me please? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

(Bear in mind that my computational physics course was ten years ago now)

You say you are solving a time-dependent system, but I don't see any time-dependence (even if `lambda != 0`). In the Schrodinger Equation, if the potential function does not depend on time then the different equation is called separable because you can solve the time component and spatial component of the differential equation separately.

The general solution in that case is just the solution to the time-independent Schrodinger Equation multiplied by `exp(-iE/h_bar)`. When you plot the magnitude of the probability that term just becomes `1` and so the probability doesn't change over time. In these cases people quite typically just ignore the time component altogether.

All this is to say that since your potential function doesn't depend on time then you aren't solving a time-dependent Schrodinger Equation.  The Tridiagonal Matrix Algorithm can only be used to solve ordinary differential equations, whereas if your potential depended on time you would have a partial differential equation and would need a different method to solve it. Also as a result of that plotting the probability density over time is rarely interesting.

As for why your potential is not constant, numerical methods for finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors rarely produce the *normalised* eigenvectors naturally, so are you manually normalising your eigenvector before computing your probabilities?